# Qt: How can I receive events fired by QWebElement objects?

Tags: qt, events, webkit, qtwebkit, qwebelement

I want to receive notifications whenever links are clicked or text fields are changed in a Webkit instance in Qt.  How can I hook up event listeners to a `QWebElement`?

I know I can put some Javascript on each element’s `onchange` / `onclick` handler, but I’m looking for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the only way (as of Qt 4.6) is JavaScript.

According to [this TODO list for WebKit](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKitTodo), there are plans to add a `QWebElement::connectEvent()` method.